# How to obtain primary key value in trigger function if primary key column name is unknown?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using postgres.
Let's say I'm going to create following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditlogfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO AUDIT(EMP_ID, ENTRY_DATE) VALUES (new.ID, current_timestamp);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I want to use this trigger with many tables and not every table has primary key with name 'id' (table can have no 'id' column at all).
So I need to find out in some way how to use primary key in my trigger function no matter which column name it has.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think you'd have to generate it dynamically for each table using information_schema.columns to identify keys..

Comment: See [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/) or [here](http://okbob.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html) for two solutions for a generic audit trigger

Answer (score 9):

What's your PostgreSQL version? You must query PostgreSQL catalog to achieve what you want. See script below:

*I'm assuming that your PostgreSQL has `JSONB` support (9.4+).*

```
CREATE TABLE public.test_table 
(
    id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    a_column TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT test_tablepkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditlogfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
DECLARE
    reg_id JSONB; 
    affected_row JSON;   
BEGIN

    IF TG_OP IN('INSERT', 'UPDATE') THEN
        affected_row := row_to_json(NEW);
    ELSE
        affected_row := row_to_json(OLD);
    END IF;

    --Get PK columns
    --You may want to extract this to a SQL function
    WITH pk_columns (attname) AS (
        SELECT 
            CAST(a.attname AS TEXT) 
        FROM 
            pg_index i 
            JOIN pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = i.indrelid AND a.attnum = ANY(i.indkey) 
        WHERE 
            i.indrelid = TG_RELID 
            AND i.indisprimary
    )
    SELECT 
        json_object_agg(key, value) INTO reg_id
    FROM 
        json_each_text(affected_row)
    WHERE 
        key IN(SELECT attname FROM pk_columns);

    --Raise collected PK
    RAISE INFO 'PK: %', reg_id;

    --TODO: your insert into audit table goes here
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_audit_cadprodu_row AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON public.test_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.auditlogfunc();

--A simple test
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (CAST((random() * 10000) AS INTEGER), 'Test');
```

Comment: Can´t make it work. -> KEY reference is ambiguos.

Comment: It worked, just needed an Alias to both KEY references

Answer (score 3):

I took [Michel Milezzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44848236/8149837) and cleaned it up so it only returns what we need, with better performance in a more concise statement. Tested on Postgres v12.1. I imagine it would work on 9.4+.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditlogfunc() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $example_table$
    DECLARE
        col TEXT = (
            SELECT attname
            FROM pg_index
            JOIN pg_attribute ON 
                attrelid = indrelid 
                AND attnum = ANY(indkey) 
            WHERE indrelid = TG_RELID AND indisprimary
        );
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO AUDIT(EMP_ID, ENTRY_DATE) VALUES ((row_to_json(NEW) ->> col), current_timestamp);
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
$example_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First I'm querying for the name of the table's primary key column, and storing it in the `col` variable. I filter the query by the special variable TG_RELID, which is the object ID of the table which caused the trigger. (See the [Postgres Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html).)

Then we can insert into the audit table. All I've changed from the question is `new.ID`. Now that we know the name of the primary key column, we can convert the new row--the row that will be (or has been) inserted, updated, or deleted--to json, and select the value with the `col` variable. This should work for both `BEFORE` and `AFTER` triggers. If triggering on `DELETE`, change `row_to_json(NEW)` to `row_to_json(OLD)`.

Comment: Be aware that this answer looks simpler but it doesn't work for those tables with a composed primary key.